# I'm searching for book out of which this question have taken.Help me to find out.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: This is screenshot of question]

This question has been asked in UPSC exam and I have seen many books but I have not got this question anywhere. Please help me to find out.

Comment: Why would you screenshot a question from this site, and then REPOST it here?

Comment: @DonThousand He's not asking for the solution to this problem, he's asking which book it came from.

Comment: Why do you think it came from a book?

Comment: Why are people marking this question as a duplicate? Perhaps it's off-topic, but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @littleO Maybe because it's got the exact same 3 by 3 matrix?

Comment: @RobertSoupe This question is asking for the book from which the other question came. So this is a new, different question.

Comment: @littleO After rereading, I agree that it is a different question. I stand by my vote, however. I think the answer to this question belongs in the "original." Connecting these two distinct questions would not have been served as well by marking this "off-topic." My two cents.